# How to tell if unit is same across the tests

Tags: r

I have multiple test that I would like to know whether all measurement are in the same unit, how can I do this automatically.

sample df:

[image]

```
df<-structure(list(Test = c("weight", "weight", "weight", "height", 
"height", "height", "Temp", "Temp"), Value = c(46, 120, 75, 168, 
61, 187, 36.7, 37.8), Unit = c("kg", "lb", "kg", "cm", "in", 
"cm", "f", "f")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The ideal results will be print a message such as  `XX test is not in the same unit, conversion is needed` if a test's unit is not unique. for sample df, it should be `''weight' and 'height' are not in the same unit, conversion is needed.`. Extra challenge part is how to modify `and` and `are` for the case only one test has unit problem.

Comment: Within `weight`, there are multiple unit.  So, wouldn't that trigger the message as well

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(Test) %>% summarise(out = if(n_distinct(Unit) > 1) sprintf('%s not in the same unit', first(Test)) else 'okay')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way where we do a group by 'Test', then return the output summarised based on the number of distinct (`n_distinct`) elements in 'Unit'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Test) %>%
    summarise(out = if(n_distinct(Unit) > 1) 
       sprintf('%s not in the same unit', first(Test)) else 
           'okay', .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: what is the purpose for `.groups = 'drop'` ?

Comment: @Stataq That is for two purposes 1) to avoid getting any warning messages, 2) more control - by default it drops the last group with `drop_last` by default (when there are more than 1 groups - here it is fine though but still may have some messages depending upon the package version)